# asp:menu does not render properly

Tags: asp.net, apache, menu, mono

I'm trying to deploy a simple web application developped with VS2010 in ASP.NET
Everything's going fine on IIS locally on the development machine, but I encouter an issue once deployed on an Apache server : The menu does not render properly, it seems it does not take the CSS into account.

Does anyone already have such an issue ? 
Thanks for your help !

[EDIT]
Appache version 2.2.22
Mono version 2.10.8.1

Site.Master :

```
<body>
<form runat="server">
    <div class="page">
        <div class="TopBlank"> </div>
        <div class="header">
            <div class="title">
                <h1>
                    My ASP.NET Application
                </h1>
            </div>            
            <div class="clear hideSkiplink">
                <asp:Menu ID="NavigationMenu" runat="server" CssClass="menu" EnableViewState="false" IncludeStyleBlock="false" Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Items>
                    <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Default.aspx" Text="Home"/>
                    <asp:MenuItem Text="Google Maps">
                        <asp:MenuItem Text="HTML" Value="HTML" NavigateUrl="~/Map.htm"></asp:MenuItem>
                        <asp:MenuItem Text="ASPX" Value="ASPX" NavigateUrl="~/Map.aspx"></asp:MenuItem>
                    </asp:MenuItem>
                    <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Liens.aspx" Text="Liens utiles"/>
                    <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/About.aspx" Text="About"/>
                </Items>
            </asp:Menu>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
</body>
```

CSS :

```
.menu
{
    padding: 4px 0px 4px 8px;
}

.menu ul
{
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    width: auto;
}

.menu ul li a, .menu ul li a:visited
{
    background-color: #465c71;
    border: 1px #4e667d solid;
    color: #dde4ec;
    display: block;
    line-height: 1.35em;
    padding: 4px 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.menu ul li a:hover
{
    background-color: #bfcbd6;
    color: #465c71;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.menu ul li a:active
{
    background-color: #465c71;
    color: #cfdbe6;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.menu ul ul
{
    margin-left: 10%;
}
```

The problem I identified is that when runnning on IIS, an asp:menu is converted into a HTML div whereas with mono it is converted into a HTML table. It seems that when running on mono, the CSS class is not found as shown in the source :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head><title>

</title><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Styles/Site.css" />
<style type="text/css">

.ctl00_NavigationMenu_0 {background-color:White;}
.ctl00_NavigationMenu_1 {border-style:None;text-decoration:none;}
.ctl00_NavigationMenu_2 {}
</style></head>
<body>
    <form name="aspnetForm" method="post" action="Arduino.aspx" id="aspnetForm">
[......]
<div class="clear hideSkiplink">
                <a href="#ctl00_NavigationMenu_SkipLink">
 <img alt="Skip Navigation Links" height="0" width="0" src="/WebSite/WebResource.axd?d=2OmH9jTSogXsrUt6aDvnYEihIak%3d_NWdhSxeypCYSJgIFnBFWuKjP9Rs%3d_f&amp;t=634787585370000000" style="border-width:0px;" /></a>
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" id="ctl00_NavigationMenu" class="menu ctl00_NavigationMenu_2" IncludeStyleBlock="false">
    <tr>
        <td onmouseover="javascript:Menu_OverStaticLeafItem ('ctl00_NavigationMenu','0')" onmouseout="javascript:Menu_OutItem ('ctl00_NavigationMenu','0')">
<table id="ctl00_NavigationMenu_0i" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">
            <tr>
                <td style="white-space:nowrap;"><a href="Default.aspx" class="ctl00_NavigationMenu_1" id="ctl00_NavigationMenu_0l">Home</a>
</td>
            </tr>
    </table>
</td>
<td style="width:3px;"></td>
<td onmouseover="javascript:Menu_OverItem ('ctl00_NavigationMenu','1',null)" onmouseout="javascript:Menu_OutItem ('ctl00_NavigationMenu','1')">
<table id="ctl00_NavigationMenu_1i" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">
        <tr>
            <td style="white-space:nowrap;"><a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$NavigationMenu','1')" class="ctl00_NavigationMenu_1" id="ctl00_NavigationMenu_1l">Google Maps</a>
</td><td>
<img src="/WebSite/WebResource.axd?d=2OmH9jTSogXsrUt6aDvnYEihIak%3d_sxBDVaG6ao8vAH1kuYRka4pbdXI%3d_f&amp;t=634787585370000000" border="0" alt="Expand Google Maps" />
</td>
        </tr>
    </table> 
    </td>
<td style="width:3px;"></td>
<td onmouseover="javascript:Menu_OverStaticLeafItem ('ctl00_NavigationMenu','2')" onmouseout="javascript:Menu_OutItem ('ctl00_NavigationMenu','2')">
<table id="ctl00_NavigationMenu_2i" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">
        <tr>
            <td style="white-space:nowrap;">
<a href="Liens.aspx" class="ctl00_NavigationMenu_1" id="ctl00_NavigationMenu_2l">Liens utiles</a>
</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </td>
<td style="width:3px;">
</td>
<td onmouseover="javascript:Menu_OverStaticLeafItem ('ctl00_NavigationMenu','3')" onmouseout="javascript:Menu_OutItem ('ctl00_NavigationMenu','3')">
<table id="ctl00_NavigationMenu_3i" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">
        <tr>
            <td style="white-space:nowrap;">
<a href="About.aspx" class="ctl00_NavigationMenu_1" id="ctl00_NavigationMenu_3l">About</a>
</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<div class="" id="ctl00_NavigationMenu_1s" style="visibility:hidden;position:absolute;z-index:1;left:0px;top:0px;">
<div id="ctl00_NavigationMenu_1cu" onmouseover="Menu_OverScrollBtn ('ctl00_NavigationMenu','1','u')" onmouseout="Menu_OutScrollBtn ('ctl00_NavigationMenu','1','u')" style="display:block;text-align:center;">
    <img src="/WebSite/WebResource.axd?d=2OmH9jTSogXsrUt6aDvnYEihIak%3d_BDOep8uzgXhnBosTOAXwCS8Rjzo%3d_f&t=634787585370000000" alt="Scroll up" />
</div>
<div id="ctl00_NavigationMenu_1cb">
    <div id="ctl00_NavigationMenu_1cc">
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
<tr>
    <td onmouseover="javascript:Menu_OverDynamicLeafItem ('ctl00_NavigationMenu','1_0','1')" onmouseout="javascript:Menu_OutItem ('ctl00_NavigationMenu','1_0','1')">
<table id="ctl00_NavigationMenu_1_0i" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">
        <tr>
            <td style="width:100%;white-space:nowrap;">
<a href="Map.htm" class="ctl00_NavigationMenu_1" id="ctl00_NavigationMenu_1_0l">HTML</a>
</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td onmouseover="javascript:Menu_OverDynamicLeafItem ('ctl00_NavigationMenu','1_1','1')" onmouseout="javascript:Menu_OutItem ('ctl00_NavigationMenu','1_1','1')">
<table id="ctl00_NavigationMenu_1_1i" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">
        <tr>
            <td style="width:100%;white-space:nowrap;">
<a href="Map.aspx" class="ctl00_NavigationMenu_1" id="ctl00_NavigationMenu_1_1l">ASPX</a></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="ctl00_NavigationMenu_1cd" onmouseover="Menu_OverScrollBtn ('ctl00_NavigationMenu','1','d')" onmouseout="Menu_OutScrollBtn ('ctl00_NavigationMenu','1','d')" style="display:block;text-align:center;">
    <img src="/WebSite/WebResource.axd?d=2OmH9jTSogXsrUt6aDvnYEihIak%3d_BiLWkNe4ZNGZnI7LWDxYAtinS8U%3d_f&t=634787585370000000" alt="Scroll down" />
    </div>
</div>
<a id="ctl00_NavigationMenu_SkipLink"></a>
            </div>
```

To be compared to the IIS version :

```
<div class="clear hideSkiplink">
            <a href="#NavigationMenu_SkipLink"><img alt="Liens Ignorer la navigation" src="/WebResource.axd?d=vNc13qxX3XhBCykqqeAM4K6DxyzXtiKPMSkmgOEeg_C2LMTfPWT8UVPq_FQ2dO_k8csGANppvDNQ8U1ILvqfCCUzXeU7VT9PTkQGnNHogQU1&amp;t=634679288663570000" width="0" height="0" style="border-width:0px;" /></a><div class="menu" id="NavigationMenu">
<ul class="level1">
   <li>
      <a class="level1" href="Default.aspx">Home</a>
   </li>
   <li>
      <a class="popout level1" href="#" onclick="__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$NavigationMenu&#39;,&#39;Google Maps&#39;)">Google Maps</a>
         <ul class="level2">
            <li>
               <a class="level2" href="Map.htm">HTML</a>
            </li>
            <li>
               <a class="level2" href="Map.aspx">ASPX</a>
            </li>
         </ul>
   </li>
   <li>
      <a class="level1" href="Liens.aspx">Liens utiles</a>
   </li>
   <li>
   <a class="level1" href="About.aspx">About</a>
   </li>
</ul>
</div>
   <a id="NavigationMenu_SkipLink"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Please post a minimal sample if possible. I don't have VS to produce one, but I do have apache and mono to test. Also specify apache and mono versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after hours and hours to try to find the solution in the web.config, I finally found that the solution came from the version of mono-apache-server. I used the mono-apache-server2 instead of the 4.
I then installed the proper version, configured the virtual host and all is working fine now !

Answer (score 0):

The anchor tag that ASP.NET puts in automatically adds the extra vertical space above the menu.  An anchor tag gets put above the menu automatically and that screws up the rendering in Internet Explorer and Google Chrome.  It works properly in Mozilla Firefox even with the anchor with the image.

To fix, add the SkipLinkText="" attribute to your ASP.NET menu control and that will fix the rendering issue.

```
<asp:Menu ID="NavigationMenu" runat="server" CssClass="menu" EnableViewState="false" IncludeStyleBlock="false" Orientation="Horizontal" SkipLinkText="">
```